# Get data from three columns using doughnut chart in CodeIgniter

Tags: json, codeigniter-3

My question is how to get all three columns data. The data displays only one column the attitudescore column. This is when displayed:

[image: json]

This is my js, it needs to specify column name inside this `datas[0]` like this `datas['attitudescore']`:

[image: js]

And this is my controller

[image: controller]

This is my model

[image: model]

Desired display:

```
[{"attitudescore":"3","teachingscore":"3","jobinvolvscore":"3"}]
```

All answers are appreciated, thanks

Comment: Please copy the codes instead of attaching captured image of codes, so we don't have to retype your codes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe what you want to achieve is like this :

```
// donut chart data
jQuery.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: '<?php echo base_url('public/employee/chart_report');?>',
    success: function (response) {
        console.log(response);

        var datas = JSON.parse(response);
        console.log(datas);
        console.log(datas[0].attitudescore);

        for (const key in datas) {
            if (datas.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                const element = datas[key];
                let active = datas[key].attitudescore;
                let pending = datas[key].teachingscore;
                let cancelled = datas[key].jobinvolvscore;

                console.log('Initial value:' + subsChart.data.datasets[key].data);
                subsChart.data.datasets[key].data[0] = active;
                subsChart.data.datasets[key].data[1] = pending;
                subsChart.data.datasets[key].data[2] = cancelled;
            }
        }

        subsChart.update();

        console.log('Updated value:' + subsChart.data.datasets[0].data);
    }
})
```

This will reiterate through the `datas` object and assign each group into each doughnut chart dataset so you will get multiple doughnut chart for it.

Comment: so much thanks @Hasta its working, I should type the codes next time :)

Comment: Hello @Hasta like what I said its working, it get the three column, but only one user read data, how about get total of this three column dynamically? :)